# Need help converting this piece of code to jQuery

Tags: jquery

Anyone jQuery experts here can help me convert the follwing javascript codes to jQuery? Although it works I'd rather see hows it's done with jQuery

```
function loadit(element)
{
    document.getElementById('container').src = element.rel;
    var tabs = document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i=0; i < tabs.length; i++)
    {
        if(tabs[i].rel == element.rel) 
        {
            tabs[i].className = "selected";
        }
        else
        {
            tabs[i].className = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the HTML

```
    <div id="tabs"> 
              <ul> 
                <li><a href="#" rel="/root/a" onClick="loadit(this)" class="selected">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="/root/b" onClick="loadit(this)">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" rel="/root/c" onClick="loadit(this)">C</li> 
              </ul> 
         </div>
<iframe id="container" name="container"></iframe>
```

And here is how I populate the container on windowload:

```
function startit()
{
    var tabs = document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName("a");
    document.getElementById('container').src = tabs[0].rel;
}

window.onload=startit;
```

Comment: Sure: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the parameter passed in (`element`) is itself a jQuery object, it *could* look like this.

Note that where ii'm dealing with a jQuery object, I tend to prefix the variable with `$` to distinguish it

```
function loadit($element)
{
    var rel = $element.prop('rel');
    $('#container').prop('src',rel);
    $('#tabs a').each(function(){
        var $a = $(this);
        $a.toggleClass('selected',$a.prop('rel') == rel);
    });
}
```

**edit**: I noticed a typo in my code above. I was missing a `#` from the line

```
$('#tabs a').each(function(){
```

Here is a very simplified live example in lieu of your HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/FKf9L/1/

Ive assumed that you're calling `loadit` when clicking one of the `a`'s which form the tabs. If this is the case it's a bit redundant, you should just latch onto the click event of the `a` in jQuery. Making the code:

```
$('#tabs a').click(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
   var rel = $this.attr('rel');
   $('#container').prop('src',rel);
   $this.siblings().removeClass('selected');
   $this.addClass('selected');
});
```

See this live example: http://jsfiddle.net/p99Q2/

**edit2**: You may as well do away with the `startit` method and just issue a `click` on the first `a` within the tabs:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabs a').click(function(){ 
        ...
    });

    $('#tabs a:first').click();
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/p99Q2/2/

Comment: I'm unable to browse the tabs using this code, it gets stuck on the first one

Comment: @Joly - Provide an example of your HTML in the original question, and i'll see about getting a live example working for you on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Joly - Yup, close enough to what I imagined. My current live examples are still relevant so i'll leave them. One thing to note is that I assume `#container` is an iframe, jsfiddle wont let me use them, so ive commented out that line and replaced it by just putting the src into a div... should make sense.

Comment: thanks for the demo! you are correct that in my case #container is an iframe. I tried using your latest code on my side but still unable to navigate between the tabs. odd

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't work cause I also populate container on windowload like this:

Comment: function startit()
{
    var tabs = document.getElementById('tabs').getElementsByTagName("a");
    document.getElementById('container').src = tabs[0].rel;
}

window.onload=startit;

Comment: I have added this to the question to provide the full picture of what I am trying to do

Comment: Thanks for edit2. The problem I'm facing that even this simple method doesn't work as I'm not getting the prompt when clicking a link: $('a').click(function(){alert('here');});

Comment: Is it inside a `$(document).ready()` as per edit 2? - you might want to read up on the basics of jQuery before trying to use it?

Comment: It is inside however even if not I would have thought that $('#tabs a').click(function(){ should be triggered for every link on the page under the tabs div yet it isn't for some reason. I'll try starting fresh, perhaps i'm missing something

Comment: Ah finally got it to work! Thanks a lot, you saved me a couple of hours probably!

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic. Reading a jQuery tutorial for fifteen minutes should teach you enough to do this by yourself in another fifteen minutes.

Comment: that's like half an hour wasted when stackoverflow is doing it almost realtime ;)

Answer (score 0):

so many ways to do it. this is using more jquery constructs.

```
function loadit(element)
{
    $('#container')[0].src = element.rel;
    $('#tabs a').each(function(idx){
      var tab = $(this);
      tab.attr('class','');
      if( tab.rel == element.rel )
      {
         tab.attr('class','selected');
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: i'll just add this here, cause almost everybody else got it wrong: look at the original code: `if(condition)class='' or class='selected'`. He is not adding or toggling or removing anything (cause we cannot assume it's there)

Comment: This one doesn't work as I'm not getting the data inside 'container' and cannot browse the tabs

Answer (score -1):

```
function loadit(element) {

    var rel = element.rel;

   $("#container").attr("src") = rel;
   var $tabs = $("#tabs a");

  $tabs.each(function() {
      var $tab = $(this);

      $tab.removeClass("selected");

      if ($tab.attr("rel") == rel) {
        $tab.addClass("selected");
      }
   });
}
```

Comment: same here: he is not adding a class, he is replacing the class-attr-value